# magento custom pages location

Tags: php, html, magento, content-management-system

Where does Magento save the custom cms pages in Filesystem?

I Created  a new page but it aint accepting the following in its WYSIWYG editor, although i edited it in the html source design of the page:

```
<style>
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, font, img, ul, li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: transparent;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}

:focus {
outline: 0;
}

</style>
```

I have also to embed some scripts in the page but it just doesnt accept that...so i though i could find the files created in the file system...where are they stored??

Comment: How do get the idea, that the CMS pages are stored in the filesystem? They are of course stored in the database – like most other CMS do as well. Note also that Magento strips some tags from page contents and cleans up the HTML markup before saving.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a custom page or a widget from magento back-end, its stored in the Database itself.

Answer (score 2):

Cms Pages are stored in db in **cms_page** table.
Cms Block in **cms_block**